# Redirect the page if the URL has content string using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have more than 200 URLs showing 404 on my page and below is the example

```
https://www.example.com/content/xyz-numbers
```

I have to redirect all the URLs to the home page so I thought if the URL has a `content` string then redirect to the home page.

I have tried the below code but not working. Would you help me out with the correct code?

### 1

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} content
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/ [L,R]
```

### 2

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} content
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com/
```

### 3

```
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

### 4

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /content/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: And "but not working" means what _exactly_ ? What do you observe, if you make a test request?

Comment: How did you make sure that a distributed configuration file (".htaccess") is considered at all by your http server?

Comment: All these rules should at least redirect ... 1, 2 and 4 to the root, but 3 preserves the URL-path after `content/`. (You've also messed around with the _flags_ argument for some reason?) Where have you put this rule? What other directives do you have? However, taking a step backwards for a moment... what's the point in redirecting URLs that are 404s to the homepage? That's confusing for users and SE's will still see them as soft-404s so it won't help SEO.

Comment: @MrWhite I have tested the htaccess rule https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ but it's saying This condition was not met.

Comment: @arkascha, not working means It's not redirecting.

Comment: But the first code sample "works"... https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=e3b4d620-bc33-4b75-90eb-c1aeaa80aa5c ??? "This condition **was** met." (Although that does match "content" anywhere in the URL-path, so it's not ideal.)

Comment: @MrWhite, I have checked the google search console and I found 200 URLs showing 404. I am not sure where I got those URLs. I am using wordpress and haven't found those URLs in my pages.

Comment: Oh Yes, the First rule is working. I tried but it was not working.

Comment: "I am not sure where I got those URLs." - That is what you need to find out. You should not be redirecting those URLs to the homepage. If you are using WordPress then you must have other rules. The order of these rules is important. The redirect in question would need to be at the very top top of the file. (But, like I say, implementing this redirect is a bad idea to begin with.)

Comment: @MrWhite, Then what is the correct way to do it? Because it's more then 200 URL and showing 404